# What is the best way to deploy 3 level global top navigation across the site collections?

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, top-link-bar, managed-navigation

There are a number of site collections that need to have a same top navigation. Currently, only main site collection has 3 level top navigation with structural navigation mode. However, it seems to me there is no possibility to deploy 3 level global top navigation across the site collections through SharePoint UI.

I have tried managed navigation but unfortunately it limits to display only up to 2nd level when "Use this Term Set for Site Navigation" is selected.

Is there any suggestion or tweaks that can be done the job?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cumulative updates installed? The issue with dynamic navigation subnodes has been fixed in the cumulative update, namely August 2013 CU.

Be sure to install the public update first:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2767999

Then get the appropriate update package suiting your license:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/08/14/august-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx

Comment: http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-2013-structured-navigation-dynamic-menus-fixed-august-2013-cu/

Comment: Appreciate your comment. I have already install SP1 + July 2014 CU on SP2013 server. So, I don't think it is not an issue.